# Is it safe to create a symlink in a dockerfile to /run/secrets/my_build_time_secret in the first stage of a multistage dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg

I have this docker-compose.yml:

```
secrets:
  my_app_npmrc:
    file: "/some/path/.npmrc"

services:
  my-app-front:
    hostname: my-app-front
    build:
      context: "/some/path"
      dockerfile: "/some/path/Dockerfile"
      secrets:
        - my_app_npmrc
```

- I cannot use a .yarnrc with `yarn --use-rc /run/secrets/my_app_someyarnrc` because yarn will not merge that config file with NPM packages (took 1 hour debug and figure it out)
- I cannot use Yarn 2 for whatever reason
- I have to use Yarn for whatever reason

It can work with an .npmrc file, but yarn does not allow to pass some --use-npmrc to specify a path in /run/secrets.

The final build will be copied in another docker stage.

So if I do something like the following, is is possible to retrieve the token in .npmrc from the docker container or image ?

```
FROM ${BUILDER_IMAGE} as builder

RUN ln -s /run/secrets/my_app_npmrc .npmrc

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=my_app_npmrc yarn install \
    --frozen-lockfile \

COPY src src
RUN yarn build

FROM ${RUNNER_IMAGE}
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder --chown=nobody:root /app/dist ./
COPY ./docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: Why do you complicate things with symlinks? read this https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#build-support-for-docker-secrets-into-your-images

Comment: My guess is that should work; there's no particular requirement that the target of a symbolic link exist.  Does it work if you run it?

Comment: @MikiBelavista yarn can only read npmrc from the current directory, and I cannot build the app in the /run/secrects directory

Comment: @DavidMaze it works indeed. The symlink is created without the --mount flags and the next line that does have the flag can succesfuly read from the symlink.